# How to reproduce this graphic using only tikz and pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I have this cool looking image from a blog post and I would like to reproduce it using TikZ and pgfplots.

[image]

I have found the property `point meta` but I do not think it's valid in this case. This plot has been generated applying a function `$f(t)\in[0,1]$` if `$t\in[-1,1]$` and assign a gradient from black `($f(t)=0$) to white ($f(t)=1$)`.

The squares are `$[-1,1]x[-1,1]$`.

Any idea aboud how to make any of those three plots?

Comment: Hi and welcome The `shading` TikZ library is your friend.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the hint, now it‘s too late to edit and there is an answer, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw squares with shading inside or you can draw functions and use `pgfplots` heatmaps to get the shading.  This is probably total overkill and way slower than it should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  heatmap/.style={
    view={0}{90},
    scale only axis=true,
    domain=-1:1,
    domain y=-1:1,
    width=3cm,
    height=3cm,
    xtick={0},
    xticklabels={},
    ytick={0},
    yticklabels={},
    yticklabel style={overlay},
    grid=major,
    grid style={thick,purple},
    axis line style={purple},
    colormap/blackwhite,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
    \begin{axis}[heatmap,xlabel={$f(x)$}]
      \node (C) at (axis cs:0,0) {\strut};
      \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] {exp(-x^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \times
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
    \begin{axis}[heatmap,xlabel={$f(y)$}]
      \node (C) at (axis cs:0,0) {\strut};
      \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] {exp(-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
    \begin{axis}[heatmap,xlabel={$f(x) f(y)$}]
      \node (C) at (axis cs:0,0) {\strut};
      \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Uoh, thanks a lot, I did know of that feature. Just one question, will \pgfplotsset{} affect other figures in my document?

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado Yes, but `compat=newest` is generally something that you want to enable for all figures.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado You shouldn't use this answer anyway.  Have a look in the PGF manual for shadings.  That is way faster to typeset, results in a smaller PDF and doesn't have horrible rendering artefacts in some viewers.